# ember-cli and brocfile app.import with glob

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I just installed a bower library that has dozens of javascript files that I need to concatenate at

```
bower_components/library/extension/*.js
```

In my `Brocfile.js` I wanted to do something like

```
app.import('bower_components/library/extension/*.js');
```

But it's telling me I can't use glob patterns in app.import.

So I tried to manually to concatenate these using `broccoli-statis-compiler`

```
var jsTree = concat('/', {
  inputFiles: [
    'bower_components/library/extension/*.js'
  ],
  outputFile: '/assets/app.js',
  seperator: '\n'
});
```

But it's telling me it can't find the `bower_components` path.

How exactly is this done?

Comment: I m afraid you have to import them one by one, they all get concatenated into vendor.js